# mapping a folder on a different network

Tags: networking, nat, wifi

I have a quite similar question like [How should I bridge two networks, given each network has its own subnet & DHCP server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/627894/how-should-i-bridge-two-networks-given-each-network-has-its-own-subnet-dhcp-s), but I have a few more additional issues.

To give a brief overview. For a sporting event I need to make a connection to another network which is not in the same IP-range. My network is 10.1.1.x, and in this case the remote network is 192.168.0.x

I also have the added difficulty that the two networks are more then 100m apart so I have bought two TP Link CPE510 which I would like to use as a point-to-point connection. Those two CPE510's are in my network so I can monitor them.

So in order to get access to a shared folder on the remote network I was thinking of putting a LinkSys E1200 (which I have laying around here) in between the CPE510 at the remote end and the switch of the remote network.

I was thinking of connecting to the remote network using the INTERNET-port on the E1200. If I'm correct, this way the router will get an IP-address from the DHCP-server of the remote network, so something like 192.168.0.50 for example.

The E1200 will have a fixed IP-address of 10.1.1.100 and I will try to turn off the DHCP (because it will conflict with the actual 4G internetrouter which is at 10.1.1.1).

So I assume I have to configure a fixed IP-Address such as 10.1.1.12 which will be forwarded to the IP Address of the pc which holds the shared folder on the remote network (for example on 192.168.0.12). I assume I need to create a NAT-forwarding for this?

Is this the right approach?
Does anyone have any experience on how I should configure this on the E1200?

For clarification I have added the [Network Schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRzts.png) here.

Thank you,
Kenneth